# Getting "Can't find UimDataStoredInSession for UiModule tooltwist.ecommerce.RoutingUIM error" when deploying Tooltwist Designer or opening a Test Page

Tags: tooltwist

While starting the tomcat server or trying to access the Test Page tab in tooltwist designer, I get the following error:

Can't find UimDataStoredInSession for UiModule tooltwist.ecommerce.RoutingUIM

Below is the stacktrace of the error:

```
2014-06-17 03:21:01,413 ERROR t.m.ServletUiModule - Error in Servlet tooltwist.ecommerce.RoutingUIM.doPost(): 
javax.servlet.ServletException: Can't find UimDataStoredInSession for UiModule tooltwist.ecommerce.RoutingUIM
    at tooltwist.misc.ServletUiModule.doPost_menuOption(ServletUiModule.java:3221) [tooltwist.jar:na]
    at tooltwist.misc.ServletUiModule.doPost(ServletUiModule.java:2995) [tooltwist.jar:na]
    at tooltwist.misc.ServletUiModule.doGet(ServletUiModule.java:2955) [tooltwist.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305) [catalina.jar:7.0.40]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.40]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749) [catalina.jar:7.0.40]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:489) [catalina.jar:7.0.40]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412) [catalina.jar:7.0.40]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339) [catalina.jar:7.0.40]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:467) [catalina.jar:7.0.40]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:338) [catalina.jar:7.0.40]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:203) [catalina.jar:7.0.40]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99) [catalina.jar:7.0.40]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953) [catalina.jar:7.0.40]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) [catalina.jar:7.0.40]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) [catalina.jar:7.0.40]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1008) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.40]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.40]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_51]
2014-06-17 03:21:01,414 ERROR t.m.ServletUiModule - Root cause: null
2014-06-17 03:21:01,414 INFO  c.d.u.UiModule - UiModule.getAlternativeUrl(module=null, url=/tooltwist/basic/error.jsp)
2014-06-17 03:21:01,414 INFO  c.d.u.UiModule - UiModule.getAlternativeUrl(module=tooltwist.ecommerce.RoutingUIM, url=/tooltwist/basic/error.jsp)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the servlet is called the first time, this file is loaded. It looks through the various projects, webdesign projects (or whatever it's called), then ttWbd, ttStd, tooltwist and any others. If the file cannot be found it will create it, probably in the web design project. From that time on, an incorrect file is used.

To resolve this, find this file **uim.tooltwist.ecommerce.RoutingUIM.xml** within your **server/extension-projects** directory. Remove all the occurrences except the one in **server/extension/ttWbd project**.